# Button trigger event doesn't fire in jQuery

Tags: jquery

So here's my problem, 
if i click on the button with the id "send" the message "Test" is send over a socket (not shown in the code).

Now I want to trigger this event if someone click's on the button with the id "send1". If the button is clicked, I get the alert on the screen, but the trigger doesn't work. Has anyone an idea?

Thx

```
$send1.click(function(){
  alert("function entered");
  $send.trigger("click"); 
});
```

Comment: Provide minimal working code please

Comment: Are `$send1` and `$send` differents?

Comment: @iArcadia Yes that are two different buttons

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve   check this

Comment: Please show the event handler attached to `$send`.

Comment: Found the failure, thx for helping. @iArcadia the event handler of `$send` was triggered with mousedown not with click.... Thank you very much!!!!